# Rollback / Un-delete documents in FaunaDB

Tags: faunadb

In FaunaDB, I would like to:

1. Un-delete a document
2. List deleted documents by collection

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You would need to [Remove()](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/write/remove) the "delete" event of that document.

```
Remove(docRef, timestamp, "delete")
```

In order to know the timestamp of those events, you can [Paginate()](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/read/paginate) for the [Events()](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/set/events) of that document and get that info, assuming your document was not garbage-collected:

```
Paginate(Events(docRef))
```

2. You would need an index that covers the references of your documents, and then you can [Paginate()](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/read/paginate) for the [Events()](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/set/events) of that index and filter for "remove" actions. Let's assume you have the index "all_posts":

```
Filter(
  Paginate(Events(Match(Index("all_posts")))),
  event => Equals("remove", Select("action", event))
)
```